# Какой тип пакета принимает сырой сокет

Tags: c, сеть, сокеты

Всем привет, я пытаюсь разобраться с тем, какой пакет видит сокет в программе. Я знаю, что единицей информации, передаваемой по сети, является интернет фрейм, которой содержит в себе заголовок и полезную нагрузку. Внутри этой полезной нагрузки находится заголовок "адресного" протокола. Потом идут сами данные, среди которых находится заголовок TCP/UDP. Правильно ли я понял структура интернет пакетов? И какой пакет получает сырой сокет, принимающий TCP и UDP пакеты?

Comment: [Пользовательское приложение, использующее raw сокеты, всегда получает IP-дейтаграмму целиком, включая её заголовок.](https://habr.com/ru/company/smart_soft/blog/184430/) (и обратите внимание на [эту](https://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw) ссылочку оттуда)

Comment: @avp, спасибо большое.